# Google App Engine for Java and Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have an Google App Engine (Java) based application which stores the file data in Google Cloud storage.

This file download servlet works fine in my local eclipse environment and when deployed to appspot domain, this works for simple text files but for any documents (displayed in the browser in a new tab), but if I try with any other binary files (doc, jpeg, gif etc) seem to do nothing, no error is thrown as well at the server side . I checked directly in the file folders in Google Cloud storage, files are stored properly and able to access it directly, but cannot do so via the app engine.

Can you please let me know if I am missing something?

The code snippet below,

```
         try {
             FileService newfileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
             AppEngineFile file = new AppEngineFile(cloudpath) ;
             FileReadChannel channel = newfileService.openReadChannel(file, false);
             BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(channel));
             BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream());
             resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + file.getNamePart() + "");
             int b = 0;
             while((b = bis.read()) != -1) {
                 bos.write(b);
             }
             bos.flush();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to stream the file yourself you should use the BlobstoreService.serve method. This takes care or streaming and can be used on files of any size.

Something like

```
BlobstoreService blobService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
blobService.serve(blobService.createGsBlobKey(cloudpath), resp);
```

Comment: Thanks would love to try this fix but eclipse is throwing a syntax error for the createGsBlobKey method - "The method createGsBlobKey(String) is undefined for the type BlobstoreService". I am using AppEngine SDK 1.6.3.

Comment: Upgraded to 1.6.6. The problem still remains, works fine in local environment but when I deploy to server the problem persists. Works for text files but not for any other format.

Do I have to enable billing for this to work consistently? So far I am operating within free quota.

Comment: Enabled billing as well, did not make any difference

Comment: Tried some additional experimentation, when I upload some .jpg files, the download happens partially and in a new browser tab image is displayed partially and download stops. Checked out all the files in the cloud storage directly, able to access it without any issues. Is this a bug in the system?

Comment: Looks like I have not deleted the older version of app engine instance. I deleted and set the current one to default with the above code, now I am getting a different error for files like .doc - Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

Comment: Have you configured your Google Storage bucket so that the applications service account has access to the objects?

Comment: Yes, I have done that and the application is able to store data in the bucket and partially able to access the data as well (.txt, jpg files only), it fails for other file format like .docx etc.

Comment: I would like to close this issue, the issue I seem to be having is in file write to Cloud storage, this is failing for any file size which is more than few KB. I will investigate further and resubmit this issue. Thanks for prompt support Stuart.

Comment: why not upload your files using the cloud storage manager to test your download path if you are having trouble getting files into your bucket?

Answer (score 0):

you'll try the following order of statements.

```
...
resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" + file.getNamePart() + "");
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream());

int b=0;
...
```